# AWS java sdk, which ports needs to be opened?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

Noob question here but my google-fu is failing me.

I'm working with an app that uses the aws java SDK to talk to aws and scrapes some info about the instances and other information. We are not hitting the instances directly, just the sort of stuff you can get from aws cli console etc....
things like describe-instances...

The app is hosted inside an internal network and traffic currently is going out via a proxy server.

I can request to have some firewall rules opened but for the life of me I can't find which ports needs to be opened and the amazon urls... is it just standard https 443 and http 80? and what are the urls, are they the same as the amazon endpoints published for the API gateway?

I can't access or modify the code, this is a vendor product that uses the latest aws java SDK (I download the sdk, unzip and put int a specified folder)

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I assume the normal http(s) endpoints are all you need to be able to access.
They are all described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) and run on standard http and https ports.